# Reference to non-existing model id: autocomplete-model

Tags: orbeon

Issue is occurring in 4.0.0 Beta 3

Here is the snippet of script that is embedded in a xf:group (references a different model) which is part of a xxf:dialog.

```
<fr:autocomplete id="bookingDescription" ref="summary" class="bookingDescriptor" dynamic-itemset="false" max-results-displayed="25" show-full-itemset-dropdown="true">
    <xf:label></xf:label>
    <xf:itemset model="coreModel" nodeset="instance('appointmentList')/descriptions">
        <xf:label ref="name"/>
        <xf:value ref="name"/>
    </xf:itemset>                       
</fr:autocomplete>
```

When the dialog box is closed via the X button or xxf:hide within an action, we get the issue as mentioned in the title. This occurs in the xforms-disable handler process. Appears to as a result of a validationException error in the xforms context Stack.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This doesn't ring a bell. Looks like a problem we would would need to reproduce, and possibly fix. But for this, we would need to have a reproducible example. Would you be able create such an example, which we can for instance run in the XForms Sandbox, keeping the code as simple as possible?

Comment: I have set up a small example to run in forms-sandbox that duplicates the issue (appears in orbeon.log) The example includes a dialog containing the autocomplete and other controls. https://github.com/jeflam/TestSnippets/blob/master/auto-complete-issue-01.xhtml

Comment: Thank you for the test case. I was able to reproduce this, for now created a issue, and we'll investigate this further as soon as we get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. I created [an issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/829) in the tracker, and you can watch that thread to get updated.